# Remove pivote attribute from JSON response in Laravel 5.2

Tags: json, laravel-5

I'm using many to many relationships using pivot table. But the problem is when I'm returning json response, the json also contains the pivot attribute as shown below:

```
{
        "id": 2,
        "job_title": "et",
        "job_description": "Iusto provident.",
        "job_industry": "Braun, Jast and Quigley",
        "job_location": "Christiansenland",
        "job_experience": 7,
        "employment_type": "full",
        "recruiter_id": 9,
        "status": 1,
        "posted_date": "2016-02-02 07:55:28",
        "skills": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "value": "molestiae",
            "pivot": {
              "job_id": 2,
              "skill_id": 1
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

What I want is something like this:

```
{
        "id": 2,
        "job_title": "et",
        "job_description": "Iusto provident.",
        "job_industry": "Braun, Jast and Quigley",
        "job_location": "Christiansenland",
        "job_experience": 7,
        "employment_type": "full",
        "recruiter_id": 9,
        "status": 1,
        "posted_date": "2016-02-02 07:55:28",
        "skills": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "value": "molestiae",
          }
        ]
      }
```

I have tried various solutions from the stackoverflow questions, but none of them seem to work. I'm new to Laravel. If you guys need more info on the model,I can post it. Please help.

Comment: Also, forgot to give you the URL so that you understand what happens - https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Skill model and set:

```
protected $visible = ['id', 'value'];
```